# Binding javascript array with asp.net web api 2 controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, asp.net-web-api

Let say that I do have the following url:

```
"/api/requests/cbd?[{"requestid":"fd45001b-339f-ac28-e053-a24c07d4e3fb"},{"requestid":"fd45001b-329f-ac28-e053-a24c07d4e3fb"},{"requestid":"fd45001b-319f-ac28-e053-a24c07d4e3fb"}]"
```

How to bind the parameters - array with asp.net web api 2 action? 
This I have tried but it is not working.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/requests/cbd")]
public IHttpActionResult CanBeDeleted([FromUri] string[] requestIds  )
{
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an array of objects so viable option would be create a class like:

```
public class Ids 
{
    public Guid requestid {get;set;}
}
```

and use it like:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/requests/cbd")]
public IHttpActionResult CanBeDeleted([FromUri] IEnumerable<Ids> requestIds  )
{
    return Ok(result);
}
```

or send only ids, without property name.

Answer (score 0):

you can keep the action in the web api like that and just change the http call into:

```
"/api/requests/cbd?requestid=1&requestid=2&requestid=3"
```

if you need the http call to be as you presented it, you can take Kamo's approach and create objects for your parameter collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your Controller:

```
    public IHttpActionResult CanBeDeleted(JObject request)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> myCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(request["NameOfYourParam"].ToString());
        return OK();
    }
```